# ng-style with background image and dynamic id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem. the following link doesn't work. the `id` is defined correctly in the scope. maybe there is some problem in the parsing. do you have any idea?

```
ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(http://assets-example.com/' + {{id}} + '.jpg)'}"
```

Comment: What link is rendered in the browser when you press F12? Do you get 404 error? Specify your problem

Comment: have you tried it without the {{ }} for id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use url without `+`es

```
ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(http://assets-example.com/{{id}}.jpg)'}"
```